# Breaking a list into multiple columns in Latex

Tags: latex

Hopefully this is simple: I have a relatively long list where each list item contains very little text. For example:

```
* a
* b
* c
* d
* e
* f
```

I wish to format it like so:

```
* a     * d
* b     * e
* c     * f
```

I would rather not create a table with 2 lists as I want to be able to easily change the list without worrying about updating all the columns.

What is the best way to do this in latex?

Comment: Very helpful, but should be migrated to http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Using the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package and embedding your list in a `multicols` environment does what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \item d
    \item e
    \item f
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't like the numbers that enumerate automatically adds, try itemize instead of enumerate.

Comment: Or [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) which allows defining custom enumerate environments - e.g. I have an exenum-environment, so that each list of examples is enumerated the same way.

Comment: What if i have an odd number list say 5. This code give 3 items in one column and 2 in the column (one on the first and the other on the third line). How can i solve this?.
How can i adjust the space between the two columns?.

Comment: What's with the huge space multicol adds above itself?

Comment: is there an easy way of alignment if there is an odd number of entrys (e.g. all aligned to top not the default spacing)?

Answer (score 18):

I don't know if it would work, but maybe you could break the page into columns using the multicol package.

```
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[Your list here]
\end{multicols}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option to avoid nesting two different environments (like `multicols` and `enumerate`).

The environment called `tasks` from the [package with the same name](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tasks) seems to me very easy to customize thanks to a variety of options ([pdf guide here](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tasks/tasks-manual.pdf)).

This code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

%\settasks{style=itemize}

\begin{document}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task[*] a
\task[*] b
\task[*] c
\task[*] d
\task[*] e
\task[*] f
\end{tasks}    

Text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\end{document}
```

produces this output

[image: tasks]

The package `tasks` was updated in August 2020 and it was originally created specifically for *horizontally columned lists* (see the screenshot just above here), the motivations behind this are resumed in the guide. If such arrangement of the items/tasks is acceptable, then this may be a good choice since it keeps - IMHO - the code tidy and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

By combining the [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package and [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package packages it is easy to define environments that are multi-column analogues of the enumerate and itemize environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newlist{multienum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[multienum]{
    label=\alph*),
    before=\begin{multicols}{2},
    after=\end{multicols}
}

\newlist{multiitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[multiitem]{
    label=\textbullet,
    before=\begin{multicols}{2},
    after=\end{multicols}
}

\begin{document}

  \textsf{Two column enumerate}
  \begin{multienum}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
    \item item 4
    \item item 5
    \item item 6
  \end{multienum}

  \textsf{Two column itemize}
  \begin{multiitem}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
    \item item 4
    \item item 5
    \item item 6
  \end{multiitem}

\end{document}
```

The output is what you would hope for:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had [multenum](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multenum/) for "Multi-column enumerated lists" recommended to me, but I've never actually used it myself, yet.

**Edit:** The syntax doesn't exactly look like you could easily copy+paste lists into the LaTeX code. So, it may not be the best solution for *your* use case!