# Convert array into latex table, but split length into multiple columns

Tags: python, latex, multiple-columns, astropy

So I have a very long table in python with two columns, I want to use the `Table` procedure from the `astropy` package (or any other package if you have suggestions) to create a table in `latex` format. Because there are only two very narrow columns in the table, I want to split up the length of the table into multiple columns instead, like this:

```
| Data1  Data2 | Data1  Data2 | Data1  Data 2 |
```

Is there a simple (automatic) way of doing this, or is it better done manually by splitting the array?

Comment: The "related" sidebar shows [breaking a list into multiple columns in latex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398127/breaking-a-list-into-multiple-columns-in-latex). That's still a few lines to add manually, but how close does that get to what you want?

Comment: You could slice the table into two tables, and then stack the slices horizontally.  Though then you wouldn't take advantage of any LaTeX-specific features for this, so I'm not sure how it will look in the end.

Comment: Is what you are asking a method to transform a python table into a latex table, or a method to break a list into multiple columns (Evert's comment)?

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the astropy `latex` writer, I can tell you that there is no automatic way to do that. As suggested in one of the comments to your question, the best thing it to split your table into three parts, stack them up and output the new table:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import astropy.table

t = astropy.table.Table([np.arange(9), np.arange(9,18)])
tnew = astropy.table.hstack([t[0:3], t[3:6], t[6:9]])
tnew.write(sys.stdout, format='ascii.latex')
```